# Should I use uniform variable to reduce the amount of matrix multiplication?

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix

I just wrote a program to rotate an object. it just updates a variable theta using the idle function. That variable is used to create a rotation matrix ..then I do this..

```
gl_Position = rx * ry * rz * vPosition;
```

`rx`, `ry` and `rz` (matrices) are same for every point during the same frame....but it is being multiplied for every single point in the object....should I just use a uniform variable `mat4` which stores the multiplied value of `rx* ry * rz` and pass it to the shader?...or let the shader handle the multiplication for every single point?.....which is faster?....

Comment: The question "Which is faster?" can only be answered by careful profiling on your part. Until you have (a) determined that this is the bottleneck of your application and (b) determined which approach is actually faster, you should just go with whichever one is simpler and more readable.

Comment: just wondering if matrix multiplication is costlier than transferring data between the cpu and the gpu....

Comment: I will also add that this sort of thing the compiler will figure out for you most of the time. just like loop unrolling and tail recursion optimizations. Like RedRobotHood said profile your code and see if it is a botleneck.

Comment: @Rob this is not something the compiler will figure out for you. It requires code changes to pass the single matrix data as a uniform, instead of passing three.

Comment: @MuertoExcobito but a optimizer could figure out that the result of `rx * ry * rz` only depends on uniforms and create a "pre-shader" that will do that once on CPU and then pass the result as uniform. Depends on the driver though.

Comment: can we create a pre-shader just to b safe..... is there any thing like a pre-shader?(havent read anything like that)....or is it only driver dependant

Comment: edit: seems like pre-shaders are not an option ....even in directx they are  executed on the cpu anyways....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While profiling is essential to measure how your application responds to optimizations, in general, passing a concatenated matrix to the vertex shader is desirable. This is for two reasons:

1. The amount of data passed from CPU to GPU is reduced. If `rx`, `ry` and `rz` are all 4x4 matrices, and the product of them (say `rx_ry_rz = rx * ry * rz`), is also a 4x4 matrix, then you will be transferring 2 less 4x4 matrices (128 bytes) as uniforms each update. If you use this shader to render 1000 objects per frame at 60hz, and the uniform updates with each object, that's 7MB+ per second of saved bandwidth. Maybe not extremely significant, but every bit helps, especially if bandwidth is your bottleneck.
2. The amount of work the vertex stage must do is reduced (assuming a non-trivial number of vertices). Generally the vertex stage is not a bottleneck, however, many drivers implement load balancing in their shader core allocation between stages, so reducing work in the vertex stage could give benefits in the pixel stage (for example). Again, profiling will give you a better idea of if/how this benefits performance.

The drawback is added CPU time taken to multiply the matrices. If your application's bottleneck is CPU execution, doing this could potentially slow down your application, as it will require the CPU to do more work than it did before.

Comment: rx,ry and rz are also calculated on the shader in my code....only theta is passed as a uniform variable for now....thank you for ur reply :)

Comment: in that case benefit #1 doesn't really apply, as you'd actually be passing in more data with a full matrix vs. 3 theta values. And - you can thank me by upvoting and/or accepting :).

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't count on this repeated multiplication being optimized out, unless you convinced yourself that it is indeed happening on all platforms you care about. To do that:

- One option is benchmarking, but it will probably be difficult to isolate this operation well enough to measure a possible difference reliably.
- I believe some vendors provide development tools that let you see assembly code for the compiled shader. I think that's the only reliable way for you to see what exactly happens with your GLSL code in this case.

This is a very typical example for a much larger theme. At least in my personal opinion, what you have is an example of code that uses OpenGL inefficiently. Making calculations that are the same for each vertex in the vertex shader, which at least conceptually is executed for each vertex, is not something you should do.

In reality, driver optimizations to work around inefficient use of the API are done based on the benefit they offer. If a high profile app/game uses certain bad patterns (and many of them do!), and they are identified as having a negative effect on performance, drivers are optimized to work around them, and still provide the best possible performance. This is particularly true if the app/game is commonly used for benchmarks. Ironically, those optimizations may hurt the performance of well written software that is considered less important.

So if there ever was an important app/game that did the same thing you're doing, which seems quite likely in this case, chances are that many drivers will contain optimizations to deal with it efficiently.

Still, I wouldn't rely on it. The reasons are philosophical as well as practical:

1. If I work on an app, I feel that it's my job to write efficient code. I don't want to write poor code, and hope that somebody else happened to optimize their code to compensate for it.
2. You can't count on all of the platforms the app will ever run on to contain these types of optimizations. Particularly since app code can have a long lifetime, and those platforms might not even exist yet.
3. Even if the optimizations are in place, they will most likely not be free. You might trigger driver code that ends up consuming more resources than it would take for your code to provide the combined matrix yourself.